# twitter api in vb6

Tags: vb6, twitter-oauth

I'd need to implement OAuth authentication in vb6
what i need is

- a free library that implements OAuth
  authentication
- if no free library, can you tell me
  how to implement mine using their
  api?
- is there any place i can download
  twiiter api documentation eg chm or
  pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are libraries for VB 6 but the logic is same for any windows desktop applications.

Check out http://dev.twitter.com/doc for oficial documentation. There are no downloadable version may be because changes happen and its easy to update the changes in the web.